# Preview the order of the unsorted cursor query in oracle

Tags: oracle, dictionary, plsql

I have this simple oracle plsql procedure:

```
    declare
      cursor A is
        select column_A
        from A_TAB; -- no order by
    begin
      for rec_ in A loop
        procedure_A(rec_.column_A);
      end loop;
    end;
```

And this is running now for ages.

When I look into sys.v_$sql_bind_capture, value_string column, I can see the current value of bound column_A, and thankfully, that value keeps changing every few minutes.

As the cursor was not sorted by anything, is there a way to see how many more records to go (until this is finished)?
In other words I would need to see the currently fetched values of the query from that cursor. Where to look for it?

This is Oracle 12 database.

Comment: How many rows in A_TAB? What does procedure_A do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dbms_application_info.set_session_longops](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm#i996999) to do this. The results are visible in V$SESSION_LONGOPS.

In your example, that could do something like:

```
DECLARE
  rindex    BINARY_INTEGER;
  slno      BINARY_INTEGER;
  totalwork number;
  sofar     number;
  obj       BINARY_INTEGER;

  cursor A is
    select column_A,
           COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
    from A_TAB; -- no order by
begin
  rindex := dbms_application_info.set_session_longops_nohint;
  sofar := 0;
  for rec_ in A loop
    totalwork := rec_.cnt;
    sofar := sofar + 1;
    dbms_application_info.set_session_longops(rindex,
                                              slno,
                                              'Process a_tab',
                                              'A_TAB',
                                              0,
                                              sofar,
                                              totalwork,
                                              'table',
                                              'rows');

    procedure_A(rec_.column_A);
  end loop;
end;
```

Note that in order to get the totalwork value, I've used the analytic COUNT() function to get the total number of rows within the resultset. You could run a separate query to get the count before looping through your original cursor, if that is faster. You'd have to test both methods to work out which would be fastest for your data etc.

Of course, depending on what procedure_a does, you might be able to avoid the need to monitor the progress if you can refactor things so that all the work is being done in a single SQL statement. My answer above assumes that it's not possible to do that. If it is, I highly recommend you refactor your code instead!

Comment: I am looking probably for a way to monitor the progress without modifying any code. Rather for data dictionary views, if any? I am running plenty of upgrade scripts, and there is no pattern, which part of those scripts are going to have performance issue (or simply running for long). Hence TAB_A can have millions of records, though from my real live example it has 10k only. And procedure_A keeps updating other tables, though for simplicity, we can assume it has a 'wait 1 hour statement' only. So I want to know, if not the exact order, then how many more records are to be processed.

Comment: You might be lucky and already have something reported in v$session_longops, seeing as you're doing a full table scan. Failing that, there's not much you can do that doesn't involve amending your code.

Comment: @user1863063 Oh, so you are *not* looking to make this process go faster then?

Comment: Wait, you have 10k rows, and each iteration call a procedure that takes 1 hour.... ? Let me do some math....  Ok, come back in 18 months or so, when your process is finished.

Comment: That's exactly where the problem is. If I could see this is going to finish in 18 months, I would break it immediately. But how to see, if the current record rec_.column_A (seen in v_$sql_bind_capture) is the very last one from that unsorted cursor, and this whole routine is going to finish withing the next hour, OR, we are in the middle of the million rows and still 9 months to go? If the cursor was ordered by, I do then query from a separate session that A_TAB, I take current value from v_$sql_bind_capture, and I know exactly where I am in A_TAB (i.e. how many more records to go).